# Mutate over every possible combination of columns

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

I have a data frame of binary variables:

```
df <-data.frame(a = c(0,1,0,1,0), b = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1), c = c(1,0,1,1,0))
```

And I'd like to create a column for each possible combination of my pre-existing columns:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
mutate(d = case_when(a==1 & b==1 & c==1 ~ 1),
             e = case_when(a==1 & b==1 & c!=1 ~ 1),
             f = case_when(a==1 & b!=1 & c==1 ~ 1),
             g = case_when(a!=1 & b==1 & c==1 ~ 1))
```

But my real dataset has too many columns to do this without a function or loop.  Is there an easy way to do this in R?

Comment: What kind of labels do you want to give the new columns? E.g. alphabetical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that `do.call(paste0, df)` will combine all of your columns into one string, however many they are:

```
do.call(paste0, df)
# [1] "011" "110" "001" "101" "010" "011"
```

Then you can use `spread()` from the `tidyr` package to give each its own column. Note that you have to add an extra `row` column so that it knows to keep each of the rows separate (instead of trying to combine them).

```
# I added a sixth row that copied the first to make the effect clear
df<-data.frame(a = c(0,1,0,1,0,0), b = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), c = c(1,0,1,1,0,1))

# this assumes you want `type_` at the start of each new column,
# but you could use a different convention
df %>%
  mutate(type = paste0("type_", do.call(paste0, df)),
         value = 1,
         row = row_number()) %>%
  spread(type, value, fill = 0) %>%
  select(-row)
```

Result:

```
  a b c type_001 type_010 type_011 type_101 type_110
1 0 0 1        1        0        0        0        0
2 0 1 0        0        1        0        0        0
3 0 1 1        0        0        1        0        0
4 0 1 1        0        0        1        0        0
5 1 0 1        0        0        0        1        0
6 1 1 0        0        0        0        0        1
```

Comment: Similar logic in base R `type_ <- interaction(df[1:3]); cbind(df[1:3], model.matrix(~ type_ + 0))`

Comment: @thelatemail Nice! Why the [1:3]?

Comment: Because there might be other columns in `df` that you don't want to be part of the `interaction` calculations. Could probably remove it from the `cbind()` call depending on what output is required.

Comment: It should be noted that using `paste` doesn't account for all possible combinations if there happen to be combinations which aren't represented.

Comment: You could begin with `tidyr::expand()` to capture all possible combinations but you'd need to list all the columns manually. It would be annoying if there are many columns to list.

Comment: Thank you so much,  this works perfectly.  I'd not come across do.call before -- it seems incredibly useful.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to David's answer, but I recognize it's a little awkward:

```
df %>% 
 unite(comb, a:c, remove = FALSE) %>% 
 spread(key = comb, value = comb) %>% 
 mutate_if(is.character, funs(if_else(is.na(.), 0, 1)))

#>   a b c 0_0_1 0_1_0 0_1_1 1_0_1 1_1_0
#> 1 0 0 1     1     0     0     0     0
#> 2 0 1 0     0     1     0     0     0
#> 3 0 1 1     0     0     1     0     0
#> 4 1 0 1     0     0     0     1     0
#> 5 1 1 0     0     0     0     0     1
```

EDIT: `funs()` is being deprecated as of version 0.8.0 of `dplyr`, so the last line should be revised to:

```
mutate_if(is.character, list(~ if_else(is.na(.), 0, 1)))
```